# How to include a font file using Bootstrap LESS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a custom-varibles.less file to override the BootStrap default file.

I want to change the font file. In some place, I would need to add

```
src: url(../fonts/MyFont.woff)
```

but I cannot find it. Where is the appropriate place to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Override **[these Less variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/7e551ecaf71cb9971990e156c54e5ee0fb758a98/less/variables.less#L73)**: `@icon-font-path`, `@icon-font-name`, `@icon-font-svg-id`

Comment: The above variables are for Glyphicons. I would need to use another font file.

Comment: If you don't want to use Bootstrap's icon classes, there's no reason to modify Bootstrap itself (beyond perhaps removing the Glyphicons classes) in the first place. You can just write a separate chunk of CSS or LESS.